# Can we only integrate over continuous functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Look at this definition:

[image]

Why is it assumed that f is continuous? Is it just to make sure the curve we get is integrable? COuld a weaker condition make a problem?

Comment: It is not necessary to demand that, it was possibly used to simplify some things or to not have to worry. This looks like from an introductory class to complex analysis, so it will likely only deal with sufficiently smooth functions (such as holomorphic functions). Regarding the question, any lebesgue-integrable $f$ should give a meaningful definition.

Comment: You are not a new user, so you probably know it is better to typeset.

Comment: @AlexR Lebesgue measure on what? The curve? Obtained how? It would be measure zero in the plane.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Are you aware of measurable functions? That may be a term you use for this. Essentially you have an underlying measure space (Here it is $\mathbb C$ with the lebesgue measure as domain and codomain) and can define the integral for all functions measurable from the domain to the codomain measure space.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, that's fine. But here you'd be integrating over the curve, which is measure zero in the plane. Hence the integral is zero when defined.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I see your problem lying in the restriction of $f$ to the image of $\gamma$. Continuity is sufficient for this, but not necessary (There are $L^p$-functions with a meaningful restriction to submanifolds). Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @AlexR The best I knew for equivalence using a Riemann integral, as in the post, was for $f\circ z$ to be continuous almost everywhere. But how does parameter invariance affect this? How can we phrase the Riemann integrable case using just $f$ (and the curve)? I'm curious if in this case continuity is required for parameter invariance.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy No, it is certainly not. A characteristic function for example with finitely many jump discontinuities on $\mathrm{Range}(\gamma) =: \Gamma$ will still be invariant. Actually anything wich can be restricted to the measure space $(\Gamma, \mathcal B(\Gamma), \sigma_\Gamma)$ qualifies.

Comment: You need the notion of a *trace* of a Sobolev function in order to define integration on boundaries of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @zibadawa timmys remark, there is a use for the continuity requirement: Integrating
$$\int_\gamma f$$
is an integral over a submanifold of $\mathbb C$ parameterised by the curve $\gamma$. Thus if we want to evaluate the Integral for a function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, we need to be able to *restrict* $f$ to the image of $\gamma$, a set generally of measure $0$ in $\mathbb C$.
Restricton of integrable functions can be guaranteed to be meaningful by assuming continuity (wich was done here), however there are some $L^p$-functions wich are not continuous but can still be restricted to a submanifold. See [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~dosilva/restriction.pdf) for a little background.

An example of non-continuous functions wich still posess a meaningful restriction is the class of simple functions
$$\mathcal T = \left\{f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}(z) | \alpha_i\in\mathbb C, A_i \subset \mathbb C \text{ measurable}\right\}$$